Type: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBDecodeException Message: Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit
i am using google speech to text in php codeigniter here my controller:
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionAudio;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\StreamingRecognitionConfig;

class SpeechToText extends CI_Controller
{
   
 public function index()
    {

        $this->config->load('google_speech', TRUE);
        $credentialsPath = $this->config->item('google_speech_credentials_path', 'google_speech');

        // Create Speech Client
        $speech = new SpeechClient([
            'credentials' => $credentialsPath
        ]);

        $recognitionConfig = new RecognitionConfig();
        $recognitionConfig->setEncoding(AudioEncoding::FLAC);
        $recognitionConfig->setSampleRateHertz(44100);
        $recognitionConfig->setLanguageCode('en-US');
        $config = new StreamingRecognitionConfig();
        $config->setConfig($recognitionConfig);

        $url = base_url('uploads/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav');
        $audioResource = fopen($url, 'r');

        $responses = $speech->recognizeAudioStream($config, $audioResource);

        foreach ($responses as $element) {
            // doSomethingWith($element);
        }
    }
}

And this is the error i am facing:
Type: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBDecodeException

Message: Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit.

i tried many solution but nothing work i work on local serve. i installed package google/cloud-speech.
pls give solution for this

Not a PHP dev. Could this Fail to push be related to the issue you're seeing?

Unrelated to the error but review the Application Default Credentials (ADC) for PHP content. Your code would be simpler|flexible if you use ADC to authenticate instead of the explicit 'credentials' => $credentialsPath
